# Orbeon - different template for different user

Tags: orbeon

I am using Orbeon form builder for generating pdf form. I need to use different template.xml in model.xml for different users.

In model template is used like:

How can I use different template.xml for different user. I may get user information from other application session object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not yet a feature of Orbeon Forms. So the simple answer is: "you can't", except by implementing this feature in Orbeon Forms.

See also:

- [#1414: Ability to specify a custom initial form template](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1414)
- [Forum thread](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Designing-defaulte-custom-form-template-in-orbeon-and-congratulation-with-releasing-Orbeon-4-4-td4657615.html)